# Euler to quaternion conversion error

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to convert Euler values into quaternion. Some parts of it are as follow:

```
       //data_set[t][8] = yaw = y, data_set[t][7] = pitch = x, data_set[t][6] = roll = z
        btQuaternion q(pcl::deg2rad(data_set[t][8]), pcl::deg2rad(data_set[t][7]), pcl::deg2rad(data_set[t][6]));

        new_pose.orientation.x = q.x();
        new_pose.orientation.y = q.y();
        new_pose.orientation.z = q.z();
        new_pose.orientation.w = q.w();

        cout << "new_pose.orientation.x = " << new_pose.orientation.x << endl;
        cout << "new_pose.orientation.y = " << new_pose.orientation.y << endl;
        cout << "new_pose.orientation.z = " << new_pose.orientation.z << endl;
        cout << "new_pose.orientation.w = " << new_pose.orientation.w << endl;
```

I have cross-checked with an  on-line [converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/quaternions.htm)  and found that the values returned somehow swapped and have sign(+ve and -ve) problem. The outputs are as below:

From my code:

```
new_pose.orientation.x = 0.0419219
new_pose.orientation.y = -0.0300053
new_pose.orientation.z = -0.184328
new_pose.orientation.w = 0.981512
```

From the on-line converter:

```
u0 = 0.9811347012447917 
u1 = -0.18632481923344862   
u2 = -0.04192188282716083   
u3 = -0.030005257724968114
```

I guess u0 corresponds to w, u1 corresponds to x and so on..

What is actually the problem of this conversion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11900/euler-to-quaternion-conversion-error/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why do you manually create the Quaternion? I would suggest using tf::createQuaternionFromRPY() in tf/transform_datatypes.h.

Given that there are 24 difference possibilities to specify "Euler angles", it's hard to tell what goes wrong here and which format the online converter expects.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-11**:
oo the new_pose is from "geometry_msgs::Pose new_pose;" It is of type Pose.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-11-11**:
I use it regularly and it works fine in any context. However, you did not post complete code thus I can only guess of what type new_pose is. (I assumed a tf::Transform which is a btTransform). Positions can usually be directly assigned, there are no conversions necessary.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-11**:
@Ahornung: I think this tf::createQuaternionFromRPY() cannot be used because it's a static function while the input arguments need to be fed are a vector of values..Please correct me if I'm wrong.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-11**:
new_pose.orientation = tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(data_set[t][6]/180.0*M_PI, data_set[t][7]/180.0*M_PI, data_set[t][8]/180.0*M_PI); Why am I still getting error of matching template problem? t is running in a loop for about 200 times..and the data_set is of type double already..

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-11**:
Any such thing for position which is coupled with TF like in orientation that you just pointed out?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-11-11**:
Yes the better way would be to just use new_pose.orientation = tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(roll, pitch, yaw). Still, that leaves the question where your original data (data_set) comes from and what "roll", "picth", and "yaw" means in their representation!

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-11**:
I didn't manually create it, i just used "btQuaternion" class functionality there.. or is it easier using "tf::createQuaternionFromRPY()"?